# Shading a strip between two intersection points of the curve with the axis

Tags: pgfplots

I wish to shade a small strip along the x-axis where the graph of a curve intersects the axis.
I have used the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line = middle, axis y line = center, ymin=-3,
    xmin=-7, xmax=7,
    xtick=\empty, ytick = \empty]
    \addplot[smooth, name path=parabola] {x^2-2};
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-7,0) -- (axis cs:7,0);
    \fill [name intersections={of=parabola and axis,by={a,b}}] (a)
    circle (2pt)(b) circle (2pt);
   \fill[pattern=north west lines] (a) -- (b) -- ++ (axis direction
    cs:0,-0.4) -- cycle;
   \fill[pattern=north west lines] (b) -- (a) -- ++ (axis direction
    cs:0,-0.4) -- cycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reason why I have used two fill statements is that in the first statement I am unable to figure how to specify the axis direction cs vector in the negative direction from b to a. Is there a way to  do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I don't know if I understand correctly your question but you could calculate the point below (a) with the `calc` library. Do you want a rectangular shape?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the `-|` path statement to get back to `(a)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line = middle, axis y line = center, ymin=-3,
    xmin=-7, xmax=7,
    xtick=\empty, ytick = \empty]
    \addplot[smooth, name path=parabola] {x^2-2};
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-7,0) -- (axis cs:7,0);
    \fill [name intersections={of=parabola and axis,by={a,b}}] (a)
    circle (2pt)(b) circle (2pt);
   \fill[pattern=north west lines] (b) -- ++ (axis direction
    cs:0,-0.4) -| (a);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the same idea an hour ago ... However is it possible to have the access to coordinates of the point below 'b' 0.4 'axis units' on the path

Comment: @Abhishek: Sure: `([shift={(axis direction cs:0,-0.4)}]b)` refers to that point.